# Trying to grasp JOINS

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT  userId, firstname, lastname, orderId
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.userId = orders.userId;
```

This returns "Column 'userid' in field list is ambiguous".
How do I get the 'userid' column to display as well, but in this order:
userId, firstname, lastname, orderId?

Comment: This isn't a [tag:sequel] question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `userid` column exists in both tables, you need to identify which you want to return.  You can do this by providing an `alias` to the table:

```
SELECT  o.userId, firstname, lastname, orderId
FROM orders o
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userId = o.userId
```

Since you mention you're learning `joins`, here's a useful site:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)